# How to find notification ID?

Tags: android, api, android-notifications, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I get the title or the notification ID that I want to Clear.
My App produces several notification .

Api is 19 .

using  `NotificationListenerService` useful?

Comment: If are created by you, you can cache the ids.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `getActiveNotifications` from `NotificationListenerService` to get all active notifications.

```
StatusBarNotification[] activeNotifications = service.getActiveNotifications();
```

Then loop through available notifications and use `getId()`

```
if(activeNotifications!=null){

  for(StatusBarNotification notification : activeNotifications ){

    if (notification.getId() == ID_TO_CHECK) {
       // do your operation
         }

   }
}
```